# Neurolab - predicted values for test set

Tags: python, neural-network

After training a feed-forward multilayer perceptron, e.g. by doing

```
net = nl.net.newff([[0,1]] * inputs.shape[1], [10, 3], trans)
err_rprop = nl.train.train_rprop(net, inputs, targets, epochs=100, show=10)
```

is there a way to obtain the predicted output values for a given test set? Also, is this explicitly mentioned in the package documentation? If so, I have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you're looking for this: http://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newff.html

```
# Simulate network
out = net.sim(x_test)
```

Comment: It would appear that is indeed what I'm looking for. I was a bit thrown off by the word "simulate" being used. Thanks!